# Get terminal bell from inside Vim terminal

Tags: terminal

My terminal can and does sound a bell for different actions such as hitting `tab` or running `>printf '\7'`. My Vim is configured to sound a bell for error scenarios such as the command `ggk`.

However, vim-terminal does not sound the terminal bell when I hit `tab` (in insert mode) or run `>printf '\7'`.

Is there a way to enable the bell in Vim terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following options are related to error bells:

- errorbells
- visualbell
- belloff

I also believe vim defaults to no noisiness, so you have to explicitly turn them on. Try `:set errorbells`and see if that gives you what you want.